# Append all key values to list that are present in value list of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My main concern is doing this more pythonically. The code below works, but seems clunky.

I have a dictionary with keys mapped to lists. I want to loop through the dictionary and see if each key is in a value list, and if so, append that to a new list associated with that key value. I will post an example below for clarification.

To simplify the problem, say that I have a dict like so:

```
my_dict = {1: [3], 2: [4,5,6], 3: [1,2], 4: [5,6], 5: [4,6], 6: [4,5]}
```

In my_dict, key `1` is present in the value list of key `3`, so we would create a new dict with `key = 1`, and `value = list(3)`

Similarly, key `6` is present in the value lists of keys `2`, `4`, and `5`. We would create a new `key =6` and `value = list(2,4,5)` in our dict.

Here would be the final output for our dict:

```
output_dict = {1: [3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4: [2,5,6], 5: [2, 4, 6], 6: [2,4,5]}
```

My code so far:

```
new_dict = {}
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    new_dict[k] = []

for k , v in my_dict.items():
    for k2 in new_dict.keys():
        if k2 in v:
            new_dict[k2].append(k)
```

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to *invert* the dictionary:

```
my_dict = {1: [3], 2: [4, 5, 6], 3: [1, 2], 4: [5, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [4, 5]}

new_dict = {}
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    for value in values:
        new_dict.setdefault(value, []).append(key)

print(new_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{1: [3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4: [2, 5, 6], 5: [2, 4, 6], 6: [2, 4, 5]}
```

The idea is to iterate over each (key, values) pair then use each value as key, `setdefault` will handle the case when the key is missing. An alternative will be to set the empty list as default value for each new key in `new_dict`, for example:

```
# set the empty list for each new key in new_dict
new_dict = {}
for values in my_dict.values():
    for value in values:
        new_dict[value] = []

# fill new_dict
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    for value in values:
        new_dict[value].append(key)
```

This will produce the same output as above, a third option will be to use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) and skip the first loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = {1: [3], 2: [4, 5, 6], 3: [1, 2], 4: [5, 6], 5: [4, 6], 6: [4, 5]}

new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in my_dict.items():
    for value in values:
        new_dict[value].append(key)

print(new_dict)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4: [2, 5, 6], 5: [2, 4, 6], 6: [2, 4, 5]})
```

Note that this returns a defaultdict, that is a sub-class of dict.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here is another version using dict comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain
my_dict = {1: [3], 2: [4,5,6], 3: [1,2], 4: [5,6], 5: [4,6], 6: [4,5]}

vals = set(chain.from_iterable(my_dict.values()))
d = {val:[k for k, v in my_dict.items() if val in v] for val in vals}
```